# MSSQL get top 4 values from 12 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some assistance here. I have a result set as per below:

```
Name | IdNumber | Subject1 |Percentage | Subject2 | Percentage | Subject3 | Percentage | (...until subject 12)
```

I need to return only the 4 subjects and their percentage that the student scored the highest in.

Getting the highest mark per student is easy, I've done it this way:

```
SELECT [Other Fields],
  (SELECT Max(v) 
   FROM (VALUES (date1), (date2), (date3),...) AS value(v)) as [MaxDate]
FROM [YourTableName]
```

Getting the other 4 is the problem.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Consider simplifying the problem, perhaps just 3 subjects will do fine?

Comment: Why not fix your table structure first? Having repeated groups of columns is a broken design.

Comment: Wont work. i messed up the above tabl, its actually percentage1, percentage2 ect the same way subject goes

Comment: the person who requested this. specifically wants it on one record with those table names thats why i did it that way

Comment: Normalising the schema design would make this sort of query a **lot** easier. If the person who demands a flat table design is stuck in their ways, perhaps create a view to satisfy them while keeping a sensible design under the hood?

Comment: How they want to have the data *presented to them* should not dictate how the data is *stored*.

Comment: this is not how the data is stored. this is the end result of a stored procedure i created to satisfy the one record request

Comment: Create a view that UNION ALL's for each subject. Then use that view in your queries.

Comment: If you created that table, change it: Create the table normalized and add a view PIVOting it for the person who requested that result

Comment: So don't give *us* the presentation form to work from. Give us the stored form, if it's actually normalized.

Comment: `This is the end result of a stored procedure i created` - It would be a good idea to ***show us that Stored Procedure***, so that your requirement can be applied there (either changing the SP, or making a new SP next to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to unpivot data as [the data you have is not normalised](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics) and then pivot data again.

Preparing data:

```
DECLARE @FooTable TABLE 
( Name VARCHAR(10), IdNumber INT,
   Subject1 VARCHAR(100), Percentage1 INT,
   Subject2 VARCHAR(10),  Percentage2 INT,
   Subject3 VARCHAR(10),  Percentage3 INT,
   Subject4 VARCHAR(10),  Percentage4 INT
)

INSERT INTO @FooTable
(
    Name, IdNumber,
    Subject1, Percentage1,
    Subject2, Percentage2,
    Subject3, Percentage3,
    Subject4, Percentage4
)


 VALUES
(   'Name 1', -- Name - varchar(10)
    1,
    'Subject 1', -- Subject1 - varchar(10)
    10,  -- Percentage1 - int
    'Subject 2', -- Subject2 - varchar(10)
    20,  -- Percentage2 - int
    'Subject 3', -- Subject3 - varchar(10)
    30,  -- Percentage3 - int
    'Subject 4', -- Subject4 - varchar(10)
    40   -- Percentage4 - int
    )
, ('Name 2', -- Name - varchar(10)
    2,
    'Subject 1', -- Subject1 - varchar(10)
    20,  -- Percentage1 - int
    'Subject 2', -- Subject2 - varchar(10)
    30,  -- Percentage2 - int
    'Subject 3', -- Subject3 - varchar(10)
    40,  -- Percentage3 - int
    'Subject 4', -- Subject4 - varchar(10)
    50   -- Percentage4 - int)
    )
, ('Name 3', -- Name - varchar(10)
    3,
    'Subject 1', -- Subject1 - varchar(10)
    30,  -- Percentage1 - int
    'Subject 2', -- Subject2 - varchar(10)
    40,  -- Percentage2 - int
    'Subject 3', -- Subject3 - varchar(10)
    50,  -- Percentage3 - int
    'Subject 4', -- Subject4 - varchar(10)
    60   -- Percentage4 - int)
    )

SELECT * FROM @FooTable
```

Unpivoting data and pivoting data:

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY percentage DESC) AS rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Name,               
               Percentage1,
               Percentage2,
               Percentage3,
               Percentage4
        FROM @FooTable
    ) p
        UNPIVOT
        (
            percentage
            FOR subject IN (Percentage1, Percentage2, Percentage3, Percentage4)
        ) up)
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT cte.percentage, cte.subject
FROM cte
WHERE rn IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
)source
PIVOT
(
    MAX(percentage)
    FOR subject IN ([Percentage1],[Percentage2],[Percentage3],[Percentage4])
)q
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Here while pivoting the data in  the result set we need to consider all the 12 combinations because the top 4 subjects will be different for each student

Comment: @SanalSunny OP can add these columns into the table.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't wish to change your table structure then you need to `UNPIVOT` the data after that you can select the top 4 subjects

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name  ORDER BY Percentage DESC) AS rn
FROM 
(SELECT Name,percentage1,percentage2,percentage3,percentage4
            ,percentage5,percentage6,percentage7,percentage8
            ,percentage9,percentage10,percentage11,percentage12
FROM r ) p
UNPIVOT 
 (percentage  FOR subject IN (,percentage1,percentage2,percentage3,percentage4
                              ,percentage5,percentage6,percentage7,percentage8
                             ,percentage9,percentage10,percentage11,percentage12)
  ) up )
 SELECT * FROM cte
 WHERE rn IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of the PIVOT and UNPIVOT operators. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The data structure is build in a way that makes things much more complicated as they could be.
You are not allowed to change that. Ok.
We need to do something ugly to deal with that ugly data structure.

Define a view that normalizes the structure. Then you can work in a normal way querying that view.

The view would look like:

```
select Name, IdNumber, Subject1 as Subject, Percentage1 as Percentage, 1 as SubjectNumber
union all
select Name, IdNumber, Subject2 as Subject, Percentage2 as Percentage, 2 as SubjectNumber
...
```

That should be much easier to deal with.

If this was for production somehow, you should try to set things straight much earlier.

Comment: Better switch to UNION ALL

Comment: Thank you Guys for all the assistance. one of the posts helped. but i cant find it now, i think they removed their post